# Unable to step in forked gem with Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pry

I forked a gem called mongoid-scroll. I'm trying to open the gem with pry command `gem-open` but I'm not able to do it since it is throwing an error.

I execute pry with `bundle exec pry` in order to Pry "see" my forked gem (set in Gemfile as `gem 'mongoid-scroll', git: 'https://github.com/bgvo/mongoid-scroll.git'`.

Then I run `gem-open mongoid-scroll` from Pry console and it throws an error:

```
[1] pry(main)> gem-open mongoid-scroll
NoMethodError: undefined method `invoke_editor' for Pry::Editor:Class
from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/ruby/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/gem_open.rb:19:in `block in process'
```

Googling for that error takes me to [this](https://github.com/pry/pry/pull/1298) issue in Pry repo. That fix was merged into master a while ago, so it should be locally (I tried `bundle update`), right?

I there any case in which specifying a gem in the Gemfile wouldn't take `master` branch?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `bundle exec pry --version` returns?

Comment: Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.1.2

Comment: `0.10.1` was released on [August, 17](https://github.com/pry/pry/tree/v0.10.1).

Comment: Thanks. How do releases work? I mean, what is the process when it comes to uploading a release to RubyGems.org?

Comment: My comment above wasn't accurate. This is what I wanted to say: How do releases work? I mean, what is the standard criteria (if any) to set up a new release?

Comment: When `gem push` is explicitly executed by gem’s author :) Some repos, though, monitor github for _new releases_ and update gems respectively. Release here means new tag in github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the error. Gemfile has as source RubyGems.org. Looking into the site, the release uploaded is the latest one (0.10.1), although `master` (and the issue I mentioned) has been recently updated. Conclusion: latest fixes have not been uploaded into RubyGems.org.